# How can I include a 3d visualization with three.js alongside bokeh graphs in the same HTML page?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to include a 3d real-time head alignment visualization alongside graphs that has been generated by bokeh. I do not know how this can be done. The 3d head visualization is generated with javascript. any idea how can be integrated with each other on the same HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML template file in [Bokeh directory format](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format) and include any local or remote CSS or JS resources like this:

directory structure (simplified):

```
myapp
   |
   +---main.py
   +---static
       +---css
           +---styles.css
       +---images
           +---foo.png
       +---js
           +---main.js
   +---templates
        +---index.html
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myapp/static/css/styles.css"/>
    <style>
       body { background: #111122; }
    </style>     
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you could initialise an show your 3D visualisation e.g. using jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var is_ready = true 
    // call here functions from your JS file
});
```

Or you could add a Button and define a JS callback for it and execute your JS there:

```
from bokeh.models import Button

code = ''' console.log(cb_obj) ''' 
button = Button()
button.on_click = CustomJS(code = code)
```

Comment: another useful link https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html the bokeh html template is at the bottom